# How can I solve error when unit testing with mocha on vue?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I using `mocha` to do unit testing to my vuetify project

I had install it. So I run `npm run test:unit`, there exist error like this :

```
npm ERR! Failed at the test-vuetify@0.1.0 test:unit script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The full error like this :

[image]

How can I solve this error?

**Note** :

When I first installed vuetify and tried unit testing, it worked. No error

After I edited some parts and ran the unit test, the above error appeared

How do I resolve this error?

**Update** :

I have updated the version of vuetify. Is that what caused this error?

I am confused to solve this error. Because all errors are located in the node-modules folder. Not in the component that I made

Answer (score 0):

I have got that problem often . I want to share what I do in that situation . I run `npm update` on project folder then I rerun test command again . If it is solve , done . If not I delete all `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` and rerun test command . Then my problem gone . Hope you problem can solve too  ..